# way to make long strings wrap to newline without removing existing newlines?

Tags: python, word-wrap

I'm working on a final project for my python course and have chosen to make a spell library which I can use while playing DnD. (yes I know there's a lot already out there but I want my own in the way I like it).

When my program prints the spell info, right now it wraps the text in the middle of words:

```
Spell: Acid Splash

Output:

Source: Player's Handbook

Conjuration cantrip

Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 60 feet
Components: V, S
Duration: Instantaneous

You hurl a bubble of acid. Choose one creature you can see within range, or choose two creatures you can see within range that are within 5 feet of e
ach other. A target must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 1d6 acid damage.

At Higher Levels. This spell’s damage increases by 1d6 when you reach 5th level (2d6), 11th level (3d6), and 17th level (4d6).

Spell Lists. Artificer, Sorcerer, Wizard
```

In this example it splits off in the middle of "each" as that is the word that is on the edge of my terminal, but other spells of course have other words that are cut off.

I want it to go to a newline either before or after words.

I have tried textwrapper, but that just makes it wonky because it doesn't account for the existing newlines. Other solutions I have found on other queries on this website also delete the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that hard to roll this yourself. Split on newline to get lines from your text. Then split that into words. Keep track of the length of words printed. If it exceeds a specified width, print a newline. Then print the word followed by a space.

At the end of each line, print a newline.

```py
text = """Spell: Acid Splash

Output:

Source: Player's Handbook

Conjuration cantrip

Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 60 feet
Components: V, S
Duration: Instantaneous

You hurl a bubble of acid. Choose one creature you can see within range, or choose two creatures you can see within range that are within 5 feet of each other. A target must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 1d6 acid damage.

At Higher Levels. This spell’s damage increases by 1d6 when you reach 5th level (2d6), 11th level (3d6), and 17th level (4d6).

Spell Lists. Artificer, Sorcerer, Wizard"""

# With a line length of 40 characters

for line in text.split('\n'):
  words = line.split()
  count = 0
  for word in words:
    count += len(word) + 1
    if count > 40:
      print()
      count = 0
    print(f"{word} ", end='')
  print()
```

Comment: Sadly this does not give the output I want. In my code it will then give the output of only several words of the spell with about 6 newlines in between.
Edit: I put in the "\n" in the first print and now it works, thank you!